# How to check if html element is visible is(":visible") not working the way I need it to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qunit

I know is(":visible") will return false if a parent is invisible, so I know why the test I'm writing fails. My question is how to get around that.

The Test:

```
QUnit.module("updateLabel", function() {
    QUnit.test("true value", function(assert) {
        var key = "exchangestatus";
        var value = true;
        var element = $("#" + key + "-" + value);
        assert.ok($(element).is(":hidden"), key + "-" + value + " should be hidden before updating");
        MyCompany.updateLabel(key, value);
        assert.ok($(element).is(":visible"), key + "-" + value + " should be visible after updating");
        //THE ABOVE FAILS!
    });
});
```

the html:

This label is in a div, which is in a div, which is in a form, which is in a div, which is in a div... The html has too much company specific stuff, so I'm omitting it, but this html is in deeply nested tags.

```
<label type="label" value="connected" name="ExchangeStatus" id="exchangestatus-true" class="control-label label-btn-success fusionconnect" style="padding: 8px 12px;">{{si011}}</label>
```

The JavaScript being tested:

```
updateLabel: function(key, value) {
    var selectInput = "#" + key + "-" + value;
    if (value) {
        $(selectInput).show();
        $("#" + key + "-false").hide();
    } else {
        $(selectInput).show();
        $("#" + key + "-true").hide();
    }
}
```

As I said in the first sentence, my assertion fails because its parent isn't visible. How do I check if that specific element has called .show(); irrespective of if it's actually visible because of its parent's visibility.

Comment: you should read the definition.  I don't think your interpreting :visible selector correctly.  https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: I've read that before posting this. What am I missing? I called .show() on the element so I would assume it's visible. In another SO post, I saw that it's not considered visible if its parent isn't visible, so I figured that's the problem. If I .show() the top level parent, then that assertion passes -- $(element).is(":visible");

Comment: show() should affect the style attrib of the element, regardless of inherited css rules

Comment: The jQuery source checks if any of the following evaluate to true (which they do not when the element is a descendant of a `display: none` element): `elem.offsetWidth || elem.offsetHeight || elem.getClientRects().length`

Comment: Okay. So I kind of figured I'm not supposed to use .is(":visible") because clearly it's not working. Is there another method that checks what I actually want it to check? For clarification, I want to assert if the element.show() has been called. Apparently that doesn't mean it's (":visible")

Comment: You could set up a spy? The other option would be to check the computed style of the element to check for `display: block` versus the `is(':visible')` method.